# MySQL error 1064 for 3rd table in file

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am having a very strange issue with creating a table in mySQL. Every time I run the file I get this error:

"ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 36 in file: 'QStoreDB.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8"

For this section of code:

```
CREATE TABLE customers

(

id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

address1 VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,

address2 VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,
cart INT,

);
```

This is the third table in my file. The other 2 are created with no issue using the same format. I have tried removing all comments, as you can see I have removed all of my constraints but even when I input the data in its most basic form (ie whats writen above this paragraph) it still doesn't run. I have also tried putting my field names in `` to no avail.

I am at a complete loss and scouring the internet has not helped me so I'm hoping some one here has experienced this as can point me in the right direction.

Comment: There's a comma before the trailing parenthesis. There shouldn't be a comma after the last statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst defining `PRIMARY KEY` you do not have to write `INT` `NOT NULL`

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

    address1 VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,

    address2 VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,

    cart INT

);
```

And there shouldn't be a comma at the end.

Comment: That worked when I removed the comma from the end it, Thank you Ali